# Two auto layouted UILabels with different font sizes: Text Top alignment

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

Is there any way to setting two UILabel text top align? both are different font sizes. [image]

Comment: u can use stackviews for this and align top.

Comment: I am targeting iOS 8. so I can't use stackView

Answer (score 2):

I can show you an example of this picture:

[image]

Code:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)styleSalePriceLabel:(NSString *)salePrice withFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    if ([salePrice rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) {
        return [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:salePrice];
    } else {
        NSRange range = [salePrice rangeOfString:@"."];
        range.length = (salePrice.length - range.location);
        NSMutableAttributedString *stylizedPriceLabel = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:salePrice];
        UIFont *smallFont = [UIFont fontWithName:font.fontName size:(font.pointSize / 2)];
        NSNumber *offsetAmount = @(font.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight);
        [stylizedPriceLabel addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:smallFont range:range];
        [stylizedPriceLabel addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:offsetAmount range:range];
        return stylizedPriceLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution you should use as it uses one label and it's easier to update the styles without having to re-jigger any layout code each time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally....I got it

```
//VerticalSpace from SmallFont Label to largeFont Label
@IBOutlet weak var dollarLabelTopSpacetoAmountLabel: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func btnClicked() {
    let amountString = self.amountLbl.text! as NSString
    let fontSize =  self.amountLbl.frame.size.width / CGFloat(amountString.length)
    let difference = self.amountLbl.frame.size.height-fontSize
    print(fontSize)
   //Your minimum font size(30).
    if fontSize>30 {
        self.dollarLabelTopSpacetoAmountLabel.constant = -(difference-
    }else{
        // dollarLabelTopSpacetoAmountLabel.constant = -30
    }
```

}